# JMeter -Groovy or Beanshell script for editing values in a excel

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I am having a JMeter test case to upload an .xls file with multiple tabs of data . The data should be unique for each iteration 
Each tab has 100 values as 
ASDFG0002
ASDFG0002
POIUY0002

The ‘0002’ needs to be replaced  for each iteration in multiple tabs .

How can I achieve this using Groovy/beanshell script

Comment: Please add some more details on what you have already tried since what you are essentially looking for is reading a file, modifying its data and using it within JMeter's environment with Groovy/Beanshell scripts. This encompasses an entire approach. Be a bit more specific on what issue you are facing while doing any of the above activities.

Comment: Hi NavnatIam new to Groovy and Beanshell scripts and uploading an xls with multiple tabs - I did not get a suitable solution anywhere .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the exact structure of your Excel document it's not possible to come up with the exact code so I can only provide generic instruction:

1. [Download `tika-app.jar`](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) and drop it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Amend the content of the file using [Apache POI API](https://poi.apache.org/) and save the file under the different name
4. Configure [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to use the new file

Here are examples of reading/writing Excel documents from Java/Groovy:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test)